# Custom comparator for int[]

Tags: java

In Java, I created a method that takes a comparator as an argument. I now want to use it to sort an int[]. I am getting an error that says primitive type int cannot be used in the comparator. Is there a way to get around this?

```
int[] arr = {2,4,1,3};
sort (arr, new Comparator<int>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(int o1, int o2) {
    if (o1 > o2) return 1;
      if (o2 > o1) return -1;
        return 0;
      }
  });
```

Comment: `Comparator<Integer>` you need reference types when using *generics*

Comment: But if I use Integer, can I use it to compare an int[]?

Comment: Yes. They can be unboxed to primitive ints and used

Comment: See how comparator is defined https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html . It says "Interface Comparator<T> T - the type of **objects** that may be compared by this comparator". You used `int` which is primitive not an object. **Use Integer** which is a wrapper class for int.

Comment: Guava has classes for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard library method to sort an array of `int` using a comparator. You would have to convert to an array of `Integer` and then use `Comparator<Integer>`:

```
Integer[] arr = {2,4,1,3}; 
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() { ... });
```

Comment: You sure can have a Comparator<int[]>. See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html.

Comment: @bmargulies the question is not about having a Comparator for int[], but about using a Comparator to sort an int[]

Answer (score -2):

Comparator uses `Object` type variables only. Try using `Integer` datatype in the code.